# Using pandas in Python, how can I make a histogram of one dataframe using the bins from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two pandas dataframes, `a` and `b`,the output of which looks like:

`a` :

```
0    4.0
1    4.3
2    4.8
3    3.5
4    3.0
```

`b`:

```
0   -1.000000
1    0.333333
2    0.000000
3   -0.500000
4   -2.000000
```

I want to use 4 bins to bin the values of `a`. To do this, I do

```
[a_binned,retbins] = pd.cut(a,4,retbins=True)
```

which results in

`a_binned`:

```
0      (3.9, 4.35]
1      (3.9, 4.35]
2      (4.35, 4.8]
3      (3.45, 3.9]
4    (2.998, 3.45]
Categories (4, object): [(2.998, 3.45] < (3.45, 3.9] < (3.9, 4.35] < (4.35, 4.8]]
```

I want to plot a histogram of `b` using the 4 bins I made of `a`. In other words, I want a histogram (or is it bar graph?) with 4 bars each spanning (2.998, 3.45], (3.45, 3.9], (3.9, 4.35], and (4.35, 4.8] on the x-axis, and I want the values of `b` to be plotted and binned accordingly. This would mean then that the first bar would have a height of `b[4]`, second bar would have a height of `b[3]`, third bar would have a height of the average of `b[0]` and `b[1]`, and the fourth bar would have a height of `b[2]`. What is the best way to do this using pandas?

Comment: Have you tried using `np.histogram` on the data and then transferring over the parameters for the other dataset?

Comment: I couldn't understand the relationship between the bins of a and the elements of b. For example, why does the first bar have a hight of b[4]? -2 is not in any of the bins?

Comment: @ayhan. The first bar has a height of `b[4]` because the first bar will span the x-axis from (2.998, 3.45]. If we look at `a_binned`, we see that the 4th element fits that criterion. I then want the height of this first bar to be `b[4]`. This would effectively result in a plot of b vs. a where a is binned and b is averaged within each of the x-axis bins. I apologize. I'm having a little bit of a hard time explaining this.

Comment: Something like this? `pd.DataFrame({'a_binned': a_binned, 'b': b}).groupby('a_binned')['b'].mean().plot(kind='bar')` I assumed `a_binned` and `b` are series.

Comment: @ayhan. Yes, precisely that! That is exactly what I wanted. The only thing I want to change is the x-axis to be continuous (maybe like 3.9 to 4.8 or something). I'm sure I can figure that out. I will read up about the groupby command.

Comment: You can have a continuous looking graph (`pd.DataFrame({'a_binned': a_binned, 'b': b}).groupby('a_binned')['b'].mean().plot(kind='bar', width=1)`) but pd.cut is returning a different width for the first bin. I don't know if it is possible to do that in matplotlib.