# Convert pandas (python) categorical x-axis to continuous values when plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a pandas series in python using the matplotlib `plot` command (i.e. `series.plot()`, where `series` is my series). Part of the series is as follows:

```
(1, 1.1]      0.000000
(1.1, 1.2]    0.000000
(1.2, 1.3]    0.000000
(1.3, 1.4]    0.003115
(1.4, 1.5]    0.002625
(1.5, 1.6]    0.000000
(1.6, 1.7]    0.001464
...           ...
(4.9, 5.0]    0.737385
Name: series, dtype: float64
```

A plot of my dataframe is [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yklf0.png) (the red line in this case). I want the x-axis to go from 1.0 to 5.0 instead of showing the bin categories. How can I achieve this? Using `plt.xticks` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question: do you want the ticks to be labelled `1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ... 5.0` or  `(1.0, 1.5], (1.5, 2.0], ...`?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Or, really, [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0] would be plenty fine, but that's the idea.

Comment: The x-variable is a category stored as a string?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. When I do `series.dtype` it returns `dtype('float64')`, but I assume that's talking about the rightmost column (i.e. the y-axis).

Note: It's actually a series, not a dataframe.

Comment: Can you post more of your code please?

Comment: Although the data isn't identical as that shown in the plot, my question is based off a previous question I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943671/using-pandas-in-python-how-can-i-make-a-histogram-of-one-dataframe-using-the-bi?noredirect=1#comment65243196_38943671), which has more of the code. The dataset I'm plotting via `plt.figure()` and then `series.plot()` is the result of `series = pd.DataFrame({'a_binned': a_binned, 'b': b}).groupby('a_binned')['b'].mean()` in the original question. I'm looking to plot it as a line graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does the series come from? Usually, I have a big dataframe of continuous-valued columns `X` and `Y`, and then define `X-bins`s according to `X` values. After that, group by `X-bins` to calculate average (or weighted average, or sum, or any other aggregation function) of `Y` to get the series like yours. If that's the case, I would suggest calculate mean of `X` in this process and plot against average `X` instead of `X-bins`. This will be more precise than taking left/right end points or mid-points of the bins for plotting. E.g.,

```
df['Xbin'] = pd.cut(df['X'], np.arange(0,10,0.1))
```

Instead of

```
ser = df.groupby('Xbin')['Y'].mean()
ser.plot()
```

do

```
df2 = df.groupby('Xbin')[['X','Y']].mean()
df2.plot(x='X', y='Y')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You pretty much read my mind. The latter method works so much better, and I was indeed doing the former. I definitely need to get more familiar with `groupby` because it's still a little foreign to me. Your solution was perfect though, thank you a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Based on our discussion, your series has an index that is a string of the intervals, eg. `'(1,1.1]'` is the index of the first item in the series.

I was able to reproduce your issue using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(0,5,.1)
x2 = np.arange(0.1,5.1,.1)
y = x1**2

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((x1,x2,y)).T, columns=['x1','x2','y'])
df['xRange'] = '(' + df.x1.map(str) + ', ' + df.x2.map(str) + ']'
series = df.set_index('xRange', drop=True)['y']
series.plot()
```

To get the ticks labelled correctly **using just the** `series` object, you need to strip the index off and pull out the first part of the interval.

You can recover the dataframe for plotting purposes via:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(series)
new_index = series.index.map(lambda s: float(s.split(',')[0].replace('(','')))
new_df.set_index(new_index, inplace=True)
new_df.plot()
```